# return boolean in async function in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to check if a user exists after login. I wrote the code below:

```
checkIfUserExists() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
      return false;
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

The function can't return a boolean because it isn't a void as expected by the function. I need (to get the date from firebase authentication) a async function. Is there a way to get a return boolean from my function above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `authStateChanges()` method returns a `Stream`, while an `async` method must return a `Future`.

Given the name `checkIfUserExists`, it seems you only care about the current value, in which case it's easier to use the `currentUser` property instead:

```
checkIfUserExists() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  if (user == null) {
    print('User is currently signed out!');
    return false;
  } else {
    print('User is signed in!');
    return true;
  }
}
```

---

If you call this code while the app is just started, `currentUser` may still be `nil`, as Firebase checks the user's credentials again at this point. If you want to **wait** for Firebase to finish this check, and get the user after that, you can get the first event from the `authStateChanges()` stream:

```
checkIfUserExists() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().first();
  if (user == null) {
    print('User is currently signed out!');
    return false;
  } else {
    print('User is signed in!');
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Tried it out yesterday and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
bool checkUserExist()=>FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!=null;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.